# Immortality in Throne of Glass series - How does it work?

Tags: magic, immortality, throne-of-glass

In throne of glass, the Fae are said to be immortal(can't age, but can still die), but then is Celaena immortal? Even if she stayed forever in her human/animal body? Or do they age when they turn to their animal form, and stop when they become fey? Do their gained age reverse when in fey form? If they don't age in their fey form, how did the 2 Fae sisters die? I know they fell in love with mortals, does that remove their immortality? What about their magic...

I might have missed something in the books, so if anyone who know can point it out? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, Aelin (Celaena) Is full Fae. Her animal form is a human. I know a ton of sites say she's demi-fae, but demi-fae (as for as I know) can't shift.

Comment: Aelin has tons of power, shown when she went to dorannel for the first time and met with Maeve. Although many sights say she is Demi-fae her mother and father both have fake blood meaning she is Fae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Is Celaena immortal?

A: Sometimes. Celaena is able to shift to full Fae form during which she stops ageing and becomes immortal. But she cannot do it at all in Adarlan as magic is suppressed.

> The moment she burst through the portal, something changed. [...] Celaena was Fae.

It happens only for short periods of time and she cannot control it at all.

> Pain flashed, and she shifted back into her clumsy, frail mortal body.

Q: Even if she stayed forever in her human/animal body?
A: So, no. Celaena's human form is mortal and ages.

Q: Or do they age when they turn to their animal form, and stop when they become fey?
A: I think full Fae stay immortal in all forms. Celaena is of mixed descend and has both mortal and immortal forms.

Q: Do their gained age reverse when in fey form?
A: According the the story, Fae do not age but there is no age reversal.

Q: If they don't age in their fey form, how did the 2 Fae sisters die?
A: By loving mortals they became mortal as well.

Also, Maeve cursed them for loving mortals instead of Fae

Comment: Update: This question was definitively answered in the most recent book (Empire of Shadows), and this answer (at least part of it) is WRONG.

Comment: More like...outdated.

Comment: Yeah, that response on my part was a bit aggressive. Sorry!

Comment: @tonysdg No prob, the author is leading us on _just_ a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Celaena' line breed with humans, and since she is more human than fae, she is not immortal, in either form. Also, when partially human children are born, their powers are either weaker, or they might not even have powers.

Comment: Do you have a quote to back this up?

Comment: So... she is more human in her Fae form than she is Fae?

Answer (score 0):

Fae become immortal/long lived through a process called settling, Aelin is mortal right now but it has been confirmed that she will settle at which point her aging process stops until her death.

So she's mortal right now and ages but will soon become immortal and stop aging, though I don't know whether she'll begin aging if she stays in her Human form for an extended time. I assume no, since if all Fae aged in the their Shift Form then they would rarely shift and we've seen Gabriel Fenrys and Rowan in their Fae forms a lot.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is Celaena immortal?
A: Not yet. As far as the series goes (up to Empire of Storms), Celaena has been growing like any ordinary person. But this was because she hadn't reached her time yet. As Maeve says to her in Chapter 71, "My sister Mab's line ran true. The full powers, shifting abilities, and the immortality of the Fae. You're likely about five years away from Settling."

As we see from the Throne of Glass Wikia [here](http://throneofglass.wikia.com/wiki/Fae), "All pureblooded Fae, and some Demi-Fae, go through the Settling - with their bodies attempting to be locked into immortal youth. It is a rough process, their bodies and magic needing months to adjust to the sudden freezing and reordering of their aging process."

Q: Even if she stayed forever in her human/animal body?
A: Yes. Eventhough her parents were only part-Fae and pure human, Celaena received the full Fae bloodline from Mab, so she is in essence just like any Fae we meet, except she just hasn't Settled yet.

Q: Do they age when they turn into their animal form, and stop when they become Fae? 
A: No. As we see from Rowan's story, he 'went mad' for about 10 years, often staying in his animal hawk form after Lyria died. And he never aged. The only reason we see Celaena still aging, whether in her Fae or animal (human) form is because she hasn't Settled yet.

Q: If they don't age in their Fae form, how did the 2 Fae sisters die?
A: The answer is only speculated in the books, but it is evident that they *weren't* immortal when they died. The 2 Fae sisters Mab and Mora fell in love with mortal men and gave up their immortality to live and die with their loved ones. Some stories say that Maeve forced them to give up their immortality when she found out they had fallen in love with Mortals, other stories say that the 2 sisters had willingly given up their immortality so as to escape being with Maeve forever. The true answer is not confirmed yet. But it is clear that when Mab and Mora fell in love with mortals, they became mortal as well. So the 2 sisters died of normal old age.

However, a Fae, while immortal may also die after living for a very long while. Again from the Wikia "While the Fae may not grow old after they have Settled, after centuries of living, their power may weaken and the Fade. After Fading, Rowan's parents passed into something called the 'void', which may be a Fae concept of the afterlife."

Q: What about their magic?
A: Not mentioned (as far as I can remember) in the books. But seeing as we have humans and Demi-Fae (part Fae, part human) who have magic, and not just the Fae who can use magic, it makes sense that the possession of magic is not restricted to Fae. Thus, Mab and Mora would likely have retained their magical abilities and (maybe) their shapeshifting abilities. But they would just have continued aging like mortals.